# Qt C++ - How to protect a file

Tags: c++, qt

My applications generates a .zip containing important files and I don't want that the end user can get access to those data. To compress I use the QuaZIP library.

My first idea was to set a password to the zip file but it seems complicated and not very secure but if you have a solution it will be enough for my need.

Otherwise do you have any idea to easily secure a file? Can I encrypt it?

Thanks a lot.
I'm Qt 5.11 and MSVC2017.

Comment: How far are you willing to go to block a *determined hacker* from getting access to this data?  Or are you trying to prevent a casual and curious user from accidentally corrupting the application data files? This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/166177) - you want to block the user from accessing a file on disk, but there's something fundamental about why you need to protect the user from his own data on his own device.  Please elaborate.

Comment: They are not crucial data so I don't need a very advanced solution. I mean even a password would be enough but I don't find an easy solution to implant it so I'm looking for other solution. In fact we'll ask to customers to extract data from a device and to send us the zip file by email for example, but we don't want they take a look inside.

Comment: Do you expect the user to type the password to unlock?

Comment: selbie if I go for password it will present in my app and only users from my company will be able to unzip it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Related: [https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35818/are-password-protected-zip-files-secure](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35818/are-password-protected-zip-files-secure)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest protection: just change the file extension (from `.zip` to `.bin` for example). For example using [QFile::rename()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#rename):

```
QFile::rename("your_file.zip", "your_file.bin");
```

Another way:
Read all the data from the file and encrypt it. You can use [SimpleCrypt](https://wiki.qt.io/Simple_encryption_with_SimpleCrypt):

```
SimpleCrypt crypto(Q_UINT64_C(0x0c2ad4a4acb9f023)); //some random number. This is your encryption key
...

QByteArray buffer = file.readAll();

QByteArray encryptedBuffer = crypto.encryptToByteArray(buffer.data());

// Write the encrypted data to a new file
QFile newFile("new_file.bin");
...
newFile.write(encryptedBuffer);
```

Then you can send this `newFile`.

On the recipient side, read all the data to a `buffer` from the file you received:

```
QByteArray encryptedBuffer = receivedFile.readAll();

SimpleCrypt crypto(Q_UINT64_C(0x0c2ad4a4acb9f023)); //same random number: key should match encryption key

QByteArray yourDecryptedData = crypto.decryptToByteArray(encryptedBuffer);
```

Comment: Good answer. I was about to suggest changing the file extension in a comment Changing the file extension will thwart about 99% or more of all casual snooping.  And it will be closer to 100% if the customers aren't technical.  That might be good enough for the OP and his customers.